# renaming multiple filenames with bash

Tags: bash

I have a list of files:

```
Mano Negra - Amerika Perdida - 01 - Mano Negra.mp3
Mano Negra - Amerika Perdida - 02 - Mala Vida.mp3
Mano Negra - Amerika Perdida - 03 - Amerika Perdida.mp3
Mano Negra - Amerika Perdida - 04 - Peligro.mp3
[etc...]
```

and I want to rename them like this:

```
01 - Mano Negra.mp3
02 - Mala Vida.mp3
03 - Amerika Perdida.mp3
04 - Peligro.mp3
[etc...]
```

but when I run

```
for i in *; do mv $i "`echo ${i#*'da - '}`"; done
```

what I get is just the usage for the `mv` command (for each file I try to edit):

```
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
   mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
   mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
   mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
   mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
[etc...]
```

Where am I wrong? I don't get any problem when running `for i in *; do echo ${i#*'da - '}; done`

Comment: Try `"$i"` instead of `$i`, or `mv` will see many parameters. Also, you may be interested in the Perl [rename](http://search.cpan.org/~rmbarker/File-Rename/rename.PL) utility (Debian-based distros such as Ubuntu have it in the perl package).

Comment: You are right, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your issue is your input files have spaces in them..
so

```
for i in *; do mv $i "`echo ${i#*'da - '}`"; done
```

turns into

```
 mv Mano Negra - Amerika Perdida - 01 - Mano Negra.mp3 "01 - Mano Negra.mp3"
```

which is not what you want you need mv to receive 2 arguments only.. ie

```
 mv "Mano Negra - Amerika Perdida - 01 - Mano Negra.mp3" "01 - Mano Negra.mp3"
```

so the solution to your problem is to change the $i to "$i"  as you have already quoted the 2nd argument.

```
for i in *; do mv "$i" "`echo ${i#*'da - '}`"; done
```